# an application of Fubini theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\lambda$ denote Lebesgue measure on $I=[0,1]$ and let $m=\lambda\times \lambda$ denote the corresponding product measure on $I \times I$. Let $E$ be a subset of $I \times I$ with $m(E)>1/2$ and ,as usual ,for each $x\in I$, Let $E_{x}=\left\{y|(x,y)\in E\right\}$.
Let $A=\left\{x|\lambda(E_{x})>\dfrac{1}{2}\right\}$ and let $B=I-A$.Prove that if $m(E)>\dfrac{1}{2}$ then $\lambda (A)> \dfrac{1}{4}$.

I know that $\int_{I}\lambda\left(E_{x}\right) dx=m(E)$ and fubini theorem will be useful, but I don't know how to use them to estimate the distribution of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Suppose that $\lambda(A)\le 1/4$. Write the integral $\int_I \lambda(E_x)\,dx=\int_A+\int_B\le\dots<1/2$, contradiction. **Except** that doesn't work here, the numbers don't come out right. The problem as stated is false - maybe there's a typo in what you typed?

Comment: Maybe the exercise itself has some problems. Thank you for your discussion.

Comment: If you change some of the numbers it becomes true... hence my conjecture that possibly you just copied something wrong.